# JIT optimization

Tags: c#, ассемблер, jit

Приветствую, уважаемые!

На днях занимался оптимизацией своего кода и пришел к выводу, что оптимизация VS сломала все мои понятия о "правильном" коде. Чисто случайно наткнулся на забавную вещь:

```
double res = (int)Math.Round(1.4);
```

.NET 4.5, в релизе, x86, со включенной оптимизацией работает в 1.5 раза быстрее, чем

```
double res = Math.Round(1.4);
```

Я сразу полез в дизассемблированный код, и наткнулся на строки, из-за которых и пишу вам:

```
double res = (int)Math.Round(1.4);
004E2643  sub         esp,0Ch
004E2646  fld         qword ptr ds:[4E2678h]  
004E264C  fistp       dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
004E264F  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
004E2652  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
004E2655  fild        dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
```

Два дня ломаю мозг, не могу понять, что делают в данном случае команды **`mov`**? Может у вас есть идеи?

По просьбам, добавлю:

```
double res = Math.Round(1.4);
00432646  fld         qword ptr ds:[432670h]  
0043264C  frndint
```

Comment: А может, оба кода приведёшь?

Comment: Классика жанра: читаем в регистр переменную со стека и следующей же инструкцией пишем ее обратно. Такой вот у них оптимизатор, увы :-(

Comment: похоже таким образом приведение в int работает. Загрузили dword впихнули что впихнулось в eax, а дальше содержимое пихнули обратно

Comment: @Abyx встречал такое же и в C++ в студии :-(

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а что не так-то? :-) судя по вопросу - это быстрее работает

Comment: @Grundy, возможно, если выкинуть два mov'а, то будет ещё быстрее.

Comment: @Grundy у меня все вычисления уже были в целых, и две лишние инструкции были совсем лишними :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я так понимаю, если выкинуть - то не округлится :)

Comment: @Grundy, почему? От перегонки 4 байт туда-обратно что-то округляется? И вообще, вопрос же как раз об этом - зачем они там.

Comment: Это не похоже на приведение к инту, т.к. считывая dword в регистр размером с dword и обратно, мы не изменяем данные. Более того, ответ лежит в переменной уже после инструкции fistp.

Comment: @Qwertiy, подозреваю что именно так :-)

Comment: @Groxan, там же еще флаги разные

Comment: @Groxan после fistp результат получается немного не в том формате :)

Comment: @PashaPash, то есть вы знаете в чем суть этих мовов? :-)

Comment: @Grundy скорее всего баг оптимизатора. Можно попробовать на connect запостить.

Comment: Думаю, что код получен при компиляции и запуске в Visual Studio, при которой, понятно, отключается половина оптимизаций.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

про firstp я нашел вот что

> Различные ошибки в этой команде могут встречаться на процессорах
>   Pentium. В процессоре Pentium III существуют некоторые ситуации, когда
>   команды FST, FSTP, FIST и FISTP с операндом в памяти не генерируют
>   исключения #P несмотря на проблемы с точностью. Обратитесь к
>   технической документации Intel за описанием всех возможных случаев
>   проявления ошибки. **Для однозначного устранения всех предпосылок
>   возникновения этой ошибки используется две команды NOP перед
>   критической командой FPU.**

У вас после fistp через те самые 2 mov которые ничего вроде не делают идет fild. Можно ли ее принять за критическую команду FPU? Скорее да чем нет, а может закладка на все случаи жизни.

Так что я бы сказал эти 2 mov работают как упомянутые выше 2 NOP. А может даже лучше.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё ссылку на источник информации.

Comment: я вот здесь нашел [ссылка](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmdfpu/FISTP) не знаю насколько можно доверять этому источнику.

Comment: Вот нашел хороший документ [ссылка](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/specupdt/252665.pdf). Страница 34, **Workaround: This condition can be avoided by inserting two non-floating-point instructions
between the two floating-point instructions.**